# select all siblings with width of

Tags: jquery

how can I select all siblings with the width of a defined value?

IE:

```
$(this).siblings(all with width of 400px).dosomething();
```

thank you

d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is what you want here:

```
$(this).siblings().filter(function() {
    return $(this).width() === 400;
}).dosomething();
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/dnug6/)